# Using Javascript (or JQuery if it's faster) is there a way to sort this more quickly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a html table which I'm sorting with javascript. The table can easily have more than a +1000 rows.

This is what I currently have and the html looks similar to this:

```
<div id="mycollection" class="table">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="A">id</div>
        <div class="B">name</div>
        <div class="C">total</div>
        <div class="D">cost</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="A">1</div>
        <div class="B">Jack</div>
        <div class="C">101</div>
        <div class="D">$5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="A">5</div>
        <div class="B">Zoe</div>
        <div class="C">5</div>
        <div class="D">$10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="A">3</div>
        <div class="B">Adam</div>
        <div class="C">21</div>
        <div class="D">$7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
function testSort(s) {
    var column = s;

    var parent = document.getElementById('mycollection');
    var rows = parent.children; // NodeList
    rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0); // change NodeList to array
    var top = rows.shift(); // remove title row

    // sort
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.getElementsByClassName(column)[0].textContent < b.getElementsByClassName(column)[0].textContent) return -1;
        if(a.getElementsByClassName(column)[0].textContent > b.getElementsByClassName(column)[0].textContent) return 1;
        return 0;
    });

    // recreate div
    parent.innerHTML = ''; // clear
    parent.appendChild(top); // add title row
    for(var i=0, l=rows.length; i<l; i++) { // add rows
        parent.appendChild(rows[i]);
    }
}
testSort('D');
```

I've set up a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/rotaercz/f6p377au/

*Additionally is there a way to make the C and D column sort correctly? It's currently sorting only alphabetically.

Comment: cache the collection of elements instead of searching DOM over and over . Need to parse text to number for numerical sort

Comment: jQuery is never faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, calling out to DOM access or (!!) manipulation facilities from *inside* a `.sort()` comparator function is something to **avoid** with all possible effort. In this case, you should make a single pass through the nodes and extract the text content *once*. That will make your sort much, much faster, particularly when there are more than a few rows.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
function testSort(s) {
    var column = s;

    var parent = document.getElementById('mycollection');
    var rows = parent.children; // NodeList
    rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(rows, 0); // change NodeList to array
    var top = rows.shift(); // remove title row

    var extracted = rows.map(function(row) {
        return {
            text: row.getElementsByClassName(column)[0].textContent,
            row: row
        };
    });

    // sort
    extracted.sort(function(a, b) {
        if(a.text < b.text) return -1;
        if(a.text > b.text) return 1;
        return 0;
    });

    // recreate div
    parent.innerHTML = ''; // clear
    parent.appendChild(top); // add title row
    for(var i=0, l=extracted.length; i<l; i++) { // add rows
        parent.appendChild(extracted[i].row);
    }
}
```

Before sorting, that code transforms the `rows` array into another array, one consisting of plain objects. Each object has the text extracted from the column and a reference back to the DOM node.

The sort function therefore can refer directly to the string without having to call `.getElementsByClassName()`.

If you have 100 rows, that will probably save several *hundred* calls to `.getElementsByClassName`; for 1000 rows, it'll save several thousand.

As to sorting by the numeric value of content, you'll have to either detect that the text looks numeric (by whatever criteria you like) and implicitly convert it, or else allow for an extra parameter to be passed to indicate that should be done. Personally I would go the second route, and change the function signature:

```
function testSort(s, numeric) {
```

Then the extraction array would be built similarly, but now it would convert to numeric when told to do so:

```
    var extracted = rows.map(function(row) {
        var sv = row.getElementsByClassName(column)[0].textContent;
        return {
            text: numeric ? +sv.replace(/\D/g, '') : sv,
            row: row
        };
    });
```

Now the comparisons in the sort comparator function will work properly when you pass in the numeric flag:

```
testSort("D", true);
```

[Link to the fixed version of your original jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8v10paym/)

Comment: Is there a way to sort the C and D column correctly? It's currently sorting money alphabetically so it doesn't look correct.

Comment: @rotaercz I just added an additional note. You'll have to explicitly convert the text to numbers. I can add an example of how to do that; give me a sec.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing reply. I'll be choosing yours as the answer but I have one more question. Would it be faster if I used the Quicksort algorithm instead of the sort that javascript provides?

Comment: @rotaercz the `.sort()` method you're using is almost certainly a Quicksort implementation already :)

Answer (score 0):

A common problem when dealing with large number of elements is the continuous redrawing of the DOM. To minimise this and make it faster you can clone the parts of the DOM you wish to operate on, do your changes and then do a replace or a you can create a string representing your elements and append the end string ONLY once.

Example:

```
var urlsDOM             = '';
resultSet.forEach(function(result){
   urlsDOM += '<li>' + result.someProperty + '</li>';
});
```

Check as well this plugin: [TableSorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter)